# Problem with setting up phpMyAdmin with Homestead and Vagrant

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

I am trying to install phpMyAdmin with Homestead and Vagrant in Laravel. When I download phpMyAdmin files I ran successful install in git bash, but when I go to http://phpmyadmin.test:8000/ I get error saying 'No input file specified'.

I think that some of my paths are wrong I just can't find which one. Every time I change something I hit vagrant provision command to update everything but it keeps getting the same error. I googled for similar problems, but couldn't find the solution that works for me. Any help is appreciated. Here is my code.

Homestead.yaml

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
  - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: C:\laravel-projects
      to: /home/vagrant/code
    - map: /Users/Gacho/code/phpMyAdmin
      to: /home/vagrant/code/phpMyAdmin

sites:
    - map: real-estate-laravel.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/real-estate-laravel/public
    - map: phpmyadmin.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/phpMyAdmin/

databases:
    - real-estate-laravel
```

hosts

```
192.168.10.10 real-estate-laravel.test
127.0.0.1 phpmyadmin.test
```

path to homestead folder

```
C:\Users\Gacho\Homestead
```

path to project folder

```
C:\laravel-projects\real-estate-laravel
```

Comment: Make sure there's a file for phpmyadmin in /etc/nginx/sites-available, and if there is, show the contents of it.

Comment: I am using windows 10. Where can I check that folder?

Comment: It would be within the vagrant environment.

Comment: I guess I don't have that folder/file, or I can't find it. What should I do?

Comment: You can reprovision with `vagrant reload --provision`, or destroy the box and bring it back up. Make sure you backup the database if you do destroy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use the `real-estate-laravel` subfolder.

```
folders:
    - map: C:\laravel-projects
      to: /home/vagrant/code              <--- missing subfolder here
    - map: /Users/Gacho/code/phpMyAdmin
      to: /home/vagrant/code/phpMyAdmin   <--- missing subfolder here
```

Try

```
folders:
    - map: C:\laravel-projects
      to: /home/vagrant/code/real-estate-laravel
    - map: /Users/Quantox/code/phpMyAdmin
      to: /home/vagrant/code/real-estate-laravel/phpMyAdmin
```

Comment: You mean everywhere where is / I put \ ?

Comment: `/Users/Gacho/code/phpMyAdmin` should be a valid windows path to the phpmyadmin folder there. Currently it's not

Comment: I changed that line and hit  vagrant provision and it still says the same error.

Comment: If you `vagrant ssh` into homestead, do the following commands `ls /home/vagrant/code/phpMyAdmin` and `ls /home/vagrant/code/` return your project files?

Comment: I did it. When I entered ls I realised that I didn't put real-estate-laravel between code and phpMyAdmin. So I put it and it works now. Update your answer if you will and thank you

Comment: I've updated my answer, is this how your configuration ended up?

Comment: different. like this.  folders:
    - map: C:\laravel-projects
      to: /home/vagrant/code
    - map: /Users/Quantox/code/phpMyAdmin
      to: /home/vagrant/code/real-estate-laravel/phpMyAdmin

Comment: Alright, I've updated again to match your project structure